# Need button click to handle action of controller

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my controller I have an action that needs to be executed when a button is clicked, I've tried using the `Url.Action` control, but that's not working.

What I've got so far :

Controller code:

```
 public ActionResult PendingBlogs()
    {
        OMSDataContext db = new OMSDataContext();

        var query = from a in db.BlogApprovals
                    select a;
        return View(query);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PendingBlogs(BlogApproval blogap)
    {
        OMSDataContext db = new OMSDataContext();

        Blog b = new Blog
        {
            BlogTitle = blogap.BlogTitle,
            BlogContent = blogap.BlogContent,
            UserName = User.Identity.Name,
            Date = blogap.Date,
            IsApproved = true
        };
        db.Blogs.InsertOnSubmit(b);
        db.SubmitChanges();

        return View();

    }
```

The button in the View:
PendingBlogs.cshtml :

```
 <td>
     <input type="button" value="Create" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("PendingBlogs", "Admin")'" />
 </td>
```

When I click on the button the page just refreshes, but the table isn't updated.

Comment: You need to do a form **post** to hit the Http post action method. Your current code makes a GET call which will hit the first action method.p

Comment: Think about it. Debug it. You really should be able to figure this out on your own. Open up the browser's dev tools. You'll see that it's making a GET request to your endpoint. You have both a GET and POST action. So it's probably not hitting the one you want. You'll need to submit a form or use AJAX to hit the correct action.

Comment: Do not accept answers that are wrong!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced same issue once, that time i was missing "**form**" in .cshtml file.

```
<form asp-controller="Home" method="post">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <h2>Create New  Job</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <input type="submit" name="answer" value="RunRegisterdJob" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: OK, I tried this, but it's giving me a 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' exception on the foreach (var item in model)